# How to save several JSON data objects with Async tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, asynchronous, mongoose

I am getting several JSON objects in the form of an array from a server and need a way to check them all against my database to determine whether I need to create a new object or not. However because of the way asynchronous tasks work the variables I am using to determine whether the object is already in my database always equals the last object in the array from the server, or undefined before I reach `Collection.findOne({...});`

Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elseArray.length; i++) {
    var tempArray = elseArray[i][0].split(' ');
    var month = getMonthFromString(tempArray[0]);
    var date = tempArray[1];
    var name = Name[i];
    var loc = "";
    if (elseArray[i][1].indexOf(':') != -1) {
        min = elseArray[i][1].substring(elseArray[i][1].indexOf(':') + 1, elseArray[i][1].indexOf(':') + 3);
    }
    if (elseArray[i][1].includes("p.m.")) {
        hour = parseInt(elseArray[i][1].substring(0, elseArray[i][1].indexOf('–')), 10) + 12;
    } else {
        hour = parseInt(elseArray[i][1].substring(0, elseArray[i][1].indexOf('–')), 10);
    }
    if (elseArray[i][2].replace(/\s/g, '') == "Event") {
        loc = "Blue House"
    } else {
        loc = "Red House"
    }
    Collection.findOne({
        Name: name,
        Loc: loc,
        "DateTime.Year": year,
        "DateTime.Month": month,
        "DateTime.Day": day
    }, function(err, CollItem) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("MongoDB Error: " + err);
            return false;
        }
        if (!CollItem) {
            var E = new Collection({
                Name: name,
                Loc: loc,
                Capacity: 0,
                Attendance: 0,
                DateTime: {
                    Year: year,
                    Month: month,
                    Day: day,
                    Hour: hour,
                    Min: min,
                    Sec: 0
                }
            });
            E.save();
        }
    });
}

if (elseArray[i].length == 4) {
    if (elseArray[i][3].replace(/\s/g, '') == "Event") {
        loc = "Blue House"
    } else {
        loc = "Red House"
    }
    Collection.findOne({
        Name: name,
        Loc: loc,
        "DateTime.Year": year,
        "DateTime.Month": month,
        "DateTime.Day": day
    }, function(err, CollItem) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("MongoDB Error: " + err);
            return false;
        }
        if (!CollItem) {
            var E = new Collection({
                Name: name,
                Loc: loc,
                Capacity: 0,
                Attendance: 0,
                DateTime: {
                    Year: year,
                    Month: month,
                    Day: day,
                    Hour: hour,
                    Min: min,
                    Sec: 0
                }
            });
            E.save();
        }
    });
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which I found worked for me was to use a for loop to loop through the array of data, then inside of the for loop call a method which checks if the data is on the server or not.

Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elseArray.length; i++) {
    var tempArray = elseArray[i][0].split(' ');
    var month = getMonthFromString(tempArray[0]);
    var date = tempArray[1];
    var name = Name[i];
    var loc = "";
    if (elseArray[i][1].indexOf(':') != -1) {
        min = elseArray[i][1].substring(elseArray[i][1].indexOf(':') + 1, elseArray[i][1].indexOf(':') + 3);
    }
    if (elseArray[i][1].includes("p.m.")) {
        hour = parseInt(elseArray[i][1].substring(0, elseArray[i][1].indexOf('–')), 10) + 12;
    } else {
        hour = parseInt(elseArray[i][1].substring(0, elseArray[i][1].indexOf('–')), 10);
    }
    if (elseArray[i][2].replace(/\s/g, '') == "Event") {
        loc = "Blue House"
    } else {
        loc = "Red House"
    }
    getQuery(name, loc, year, month, date, hour, min);

    if (elseArray[i].length == 4) {
        if (elseArray[i][3].replace(/\s/g, '') == "Event") {
            loc = "Blue House"
        } else {
            loc = "Red House"
        }
        getQuery(name, loc, year, month, date, hour, min);
    }
}
```

In the for loop looping through the array of data from the server I read in the data, store everything in variables, and then call `getQuery()` which checks the database for the current data and creates a new JSON object if the current data was not found in the database.

`getQuery()` method:

```
function getQuery()(name, loc, year, month, day, hour, min) {
Collection.findOne({
    Name: name,
    Loc: loc,
    "DateTime.Year": year,
    "DateTime.Month": month,
    "DateTime.Day": day
}, function(err, CollItem) {
    if (err) {
        res.send("MongoDB Error: " + err);
        return false;
    }
    if (!CollItem) {
        var E = new Collection({
            Name: name,
            Loc: loc,
            Capacity: 0,
            Attendance: 0,
            DateTime: {
                Year: year,
                Month: month,
                Day: day,
                Hour: hour,
                Min: min,
                Sec: 0
            }
        });
        E.save();
    }
});
}
```

In the method `getQuery()`, if an object is found which matches the `name, loc, year, etc...` which is passed in nothing happens otherwise the data is saved and stored on in the database.

In short, I made the `Collection.findOne({...});` into its own method called `getQuery()` to work around the speed differences between Async tasks and `Collection.findOne({...});`.